# Google Earth Engine band values are empty/'None'

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am working on a project which includes creating a time series analysis of NDVI values over time(and getting ndvi values/images with an ndvi mask over them). I decided to use the google earth engine api in python, and I am using their supported Google Cloud Datalab(Jupyter Notebook).

When I try to retrieve band values from a collection region, I am getting values of 'None'(which is shown below in the code snippet). However, some coordinates give valid band values, and others(most) give values of 'None'. I am confused, because the date range that I am filtering is quite large(1 year), and I am getting real images with different coordinates and timestamps, but their band values are all filled in with 'None'.

My question is: Why do some coordinates give valid band values, and not others? Additionally, how can I make sure that a set of coordinates that I pick will have band values?

(I didn't put the dependencies code segment to save space, but I can include it if needed. I am not getting any errors).

```
# Set start and end date
startTime = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2)
endTime = datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 2)

# Create image collection
collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR').filterDate(startTime, endTime).limit(2500)
point = {'type':'Point', 'coordinates':[32.9661871, -117.1794014]};
#Retrieve information over image collection
info = collection.getRegion(point,500).getInfo()
pp.pprint(info)
```

Which results in:
[[u'id',
  u'longitude',
  u'latitude',
  u'time',
  u'B1',
  u'B2',
  u'B3',
  u'B4',
  u'B5',
  u'B6',
  u'B7',
  u'B10',
  u'B11',
  u'sr_aerosol',
  u'pixel_qa',
  u'radsat_qa'],
 [u'LC08_001004_20140524',
  32.96592513897614,
  -117.17849144876068,
  1400940473520.0,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None],
 [u'LC08_001004_20140609',
  32.96592513897614,
  -117.17849144876068,
  1402322883990.0,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None,
  None], + 2500 similar elements...